# Not able to connect access database to visual studio

Tags: c#, .net, ms-access, oledbconnection

I am trying to conncet access database to my visual studio but i face this type of error "The Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" provider is not registered on the local machine.

I look at some solutions on google i got that after downloading Microsoft Access Database Engine on Local machine we are able to connect database.But i still face this problem. So What should i do for it? .And i am using Windows10 but i use Ms office 2007 and my system is 64-bit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFrPR.png)

Comment: [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) can verify whether you have 32-bit or 64-bit ACE installed. Then you can tell Visual Studio to target your app for the same "bitness".

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention if you planning to use the x32 bit or x64 version of access.

So, assuming you downloaded the access data engine? You have to choose or decide WHICH bit size version you wish to use.

That download can be found here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=13255

And you have two choices:

[image]

Ok, next up?

You MUST set and FORCE your project to the correct bit size.

that is this project setting in VS.

[image]

So, if  you using x32 version, then use x86 version, and if adopting x64 version, then set your project to x64.

So, don't use "any" for your project setting - you have to force the issue.

So, try setting up a connection. You have two choices:

```
Use the ODBC provider,
or
Use the oleDB provider
```

So, ok, ODBC? then that connection setting should look like this:

For odbc, the connecton string should look like this:

```
Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};
dbq=C:\TEST\test444.accdb;uid=Admin
```

for oleDB, the connection string should look like this:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\test\test45.accdb
```

And in both cases, you can as a normal rule, leave the password blank.

Assuming  you used the project settings, say here:

[image]

(and you can use the connection string builder in above. BUT BE VERY carefull, if you are running access x64, then the test connection WILL ALWAYS ALWAYS fail, since VS is a x32 bit applcation, but if you run your code, and the project was forced to x64 bits, then the connection will work DISPITE VS and the test connection telling you it does not.

So, to use the above ODBC connection, we have this:

```
        using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessODBC))
        {
            string strSQL =
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (OdbcCommand cmdSQL = new OdbcCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                dataGridView1.DataSource = rstData;
            }
        }
```

And for oledb, we would have this:

```
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.AccessDB))
        {
            string strSQL =
                "SELECT * FROM tblHotels ORDER BY HotelName";
            using (OleDbCommand cmdSQL = new OleDbCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());

                dataGridView1.DataSource = rstData;
            }
        }
```

So, which provider to use?

Most use and suggest oleDB.

However, I think using ODBC is not all that bad of a choice. the reason is you can change the connection to sql server, or other database systems, and NOT have to change your provider, but only the connection string.

While you can sort of do the same with oleDB, there is now MUCH better support for ODBC database systems.